# mvnw failing when trying to package or run spring-petclinic

Tags: package

I can't run or package the application following the instructions. I`m getting the next error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain
```

for both

```
./mvnw spring-boot:run
./mvnw package
```

As googling doesn't help and the error by itself not clear for me I`m stuck. Maybe someone had the same issue and resolved it?)

my environment:
java -version

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_292-8u292-b10-0ubuntu1~20.04-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)
```

mvn --version

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3
OS name: "linux", version: "5.8.0-59-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

NOTE
I've tried `mvn -N io.takari:maven:wrapper` it doesn't resolve issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this issue, the problem was with the directory name(in the path to the cloned repository), it contained the ':' symbol, I`ve replaced it with dash, and no error anymore

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when trying to [mess around with Spring Boot](https://spring.io/quickstart). I run the command `./mvnw spring-boot:run` and get

```
./mvnw: line 280: /Users/alesh/projects/spring-boot-demo/.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.properties: No such file or directory
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Warning: Failed to create the file 
Warning: /Users/alesh/projects/spring-boot-demo/.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar:
Warning:  No such file or directory
  1 58727    1  1033    0     0   4152      0  0:00:14 --:--:--  0:00:14  4251
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain
```

Running this fixed it for me: `mvn spring-boot:run`.

(I have JDK and Maven installed.)